# Is there a way to reset Achievement progress for my GameCenter sandbox account?

Tags: sandbox, reset, game-center, achievements

I have a GameCenter Sandbox-Account have tested my game, earned achievements, etc. 
Now I've made some changes and want to test earning Achievements again!

Do I have to make an entire new Sandbox-Account or is there a way to **reset** my account?

Comment: I think you're better off posting this on the [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: I thought it was better to ask the developers since normal players never get a sandbox-account, but maybe it functions the same and I'd indeed be better off asking the players?

Answer (score 12):

The following code is from the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKit_Guide.pdf).

```cs
- (void) resetAchievements
{
   // Clear all locally saved achievement objects.
   achievementsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   // Clear all progress saved on Game Center
   [GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
   {
      if (error != nil)
      // handle errors
   }];
}
```

Also have a look at Apple's sample project [GKTapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
// Reset all the achievements for local player 
- (void)resetAchievements
{
    [GKAchievement resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSError *error) 
     {
        if (!error) {
             [storedAchievements release];
            storedAchievements = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

            // overwrite any previously stored file
             [self writeStoredAchievements];              
        } else {
            // Error clearing achievements. 
         }
     }];
}
```